# WordPress redirect always redirects to 404

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

In a functions.php I use a redirect to show a profile page when a correct code is added to the homepage. It worked before, but ever since a third party coder added some changes it no longer does. I initially added an isset to remove a `Undefined index: post_type` error. Now there are no more errors, but instead of being redirected to the profile view I am being redirected to the final else statement: a 404. Here is the redirect code:

```
    function my_template_redirect()
{
    global $wp;
    global $wp_query;

    if (isset($_REQUEST['post_type']))

    { 
    if ($_REQUEST['post_type']=="signup")
    {
        // Let's look for the property.php template file in the current theme
        if (have_posts())
        {
            include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/register.php');
            die();
        }
        else
        {
            $wp_query->is_404 = true;
        }
    }else if ($_REQUEST['post_type']=="viewprofile")
    {
        // Let's look for the property.php template file in the current theme
        if (have_posts())
        {
            include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/viewprofile.php');
            die();
        }
        else
        {
            $wp_query->is_404 = true;
        }
    }
}
    }
```

Profile view code is here: http://pastebin.com/1Nkxp0Zv . Form code on home is:

```
<div class="container">
                    <form action="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/?post_type=viewprofile" method="post">
                    <span>Enter your code here:</span><input name="enterCodeId" type="text" class="inputBox" /><input type="submit" value="GO!" class="go" />
                    </form>
              </div>
```

Any ideas why my key is no longer accepted and keep on getting 404-ed via the last else statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the only way to get to that is by not having any posts, or if the have_posts() function returns a falsy value. That's where you will find your error.

Comment: Yeah, that could just be it. So I need to have a user have posts now to get to see the profile view. Need to change that somehow. Did change the post value to myaccesskey as that is what is used to generate keys now, but I still get to the 404. And, yeah, that must be because this user has no posts...

Comment: To me, it seems like you should just go ahead and run the include(...viewprofile.php) code and remove that `else` entirely.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. Should be safe like this as well I'd say and now I can access the user's profile even when there are now posts. Thanks!